# How to get a list of google-chrome extensions from the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, browser-addons

As I am unable to open the chrome browser on a remote Linux system (Ubuntu 16.04), I cannot open the browser to see the installed add-ons.

How can I, per command line, see the addons installed with `google-chrome`.

Comment: Refer to this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/linux_hosting

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself; you can run the following command:

```bsh
for i in $(find ~/.config/google-chrome/*/Extensions -name 'manifest.json'); do
  n=$(grep -hIr name $i| cut -f4 -d '"'| sort)
  u="https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/"
  ue=$(basename $(dirname $(dirname $i)))
  echo -e "$n:\n$u$ue\n"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

For Chromium with snap installed, I have below, with `jq` command being pretty easy and a better way than `sed`/`cut`/`awk`/`sort`/etc.:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

ext_dir="$HOME/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Extensions/"

for i in $(find $ext_dir -name 'manifest.json'); do
  n=$(jq ".name" $i)
  update=$(jq ".update_url" $i)
    # n=$(grep -hIr name $i| cut -f4 -d '"'| sort)
    # u="https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/"
  ue=$(basename $(dirname $(dirname $i)))
  echo -e "$ue,$n:\n$update\n"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a make_crx.sh file, people can create crx file from working chromium extensions.

```
 1  #!/bin/bash
 2  ext_dir="$HOME/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Extensions/"
 3  my_ext=$(pwd)
 4  for ext in $(find $ext_dir -name 'manifest.json')
 5  do 
 6      root_dir=$(dirname $ext)
 7      id=$(basename $(dirname $root_dir))
 8      name=$(jq ".name" $ext)
 9      # u="https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/"
10      echo -e "Name: $name, ID: $id\nRoot_Dir: $root_dir\n"
11      chromium --pack-extension=$root_dir 2>/dev/null
12      mv $root_dir/../*.crx $my_ext/$id.crx
13      mv $root_dir/../*.pem $my_ext/$id.pem
14  done
```